# Enthought Canopy & IPython QtConsole ignore logging.basicConfig

Tags: python-2.7, logging, enthought

Using [Enthought Canopy](https://enthought.com) v1.4 on Mac (Mavericks), logging statements that are debug or info are ignored, even with a logging level of `DEBUG`. The PyLab backend is set to Interactive (Qt4). Here is an example and its output:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

logging.debug('variable is nil')
logging.info('hey! listen!')
logging.warning('watch out!')
logging.error('an error happened')
logging.critical('a critical event happened')
```

Will log to Canopy’s “interactive data-analysis environment” built-in console:

```
WARNING:root:watch out!
ERROR:root:an error happened
CRITICAL:root:a critical event happened
```

Running this in Terminal will ignore debug/info and output right there. Interestingly setting the `logging.basicConfig` to use a log file and then running in Terminal will not ignore debug/info.

I can workaround this, but is there a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting. Canopy's IPython shell is an "IPython Qtconsole", and what you are seeing is the normal behavior of QtConsole. To see this, open a standard (non-Canopy) Qtconsole from a Terminal with `ipython qtconsole`

Then in this Qtconsole, type `logging.root.handlers`. You will see that the root logger is already configured with one handler.

As described at https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig, this causes the convenience function `basicConfig` to do nothing.

In contrast, the same sequence in a simple IPython terminal session shows that the root logger is not initially configured with any handlers. I don't know the reason for this difference.

However, armed with this knowledge, you can easily change the level of the root logger with:

```
logging.root.level = logging.DEBUG
```

Comment: I just stumbled across this.  For the record, it turns out that it's the tornado package that's calling `logging.basicConfig` when the zeromq ioloop is started as part of the IPython qtconsole bootstrap process. Here's a [source link](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/v4.2.1/tornado/ioloop.py#L374)

Answer (score 0):

(Response to initial question which did not include basicConfig in code snippet):
That's expected behavior in Python.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logger-objects

> Note that the root logger is created with level WARNING.

Comment: This is also the case for the `DEBUG` logging level. `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)`.